# Getting 0 result on search in Node JS

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, search, find

I have Created a Node JS API for Search and stored some data in MongoDB.
My data is stored like example:

```
FN02 ROL

FN02 ROM

FN02 RON

FN02 ROO

FN02 ROS

FN02 ROT

FN02 ROV

FN02 ROW

FN02 ROX

FN02 ROY
```

So when i search with fn02 it works well but when i add one more parameter like fno2r it doesn't work i think it would be because of space but not sure so i trim that space but still it doesn't work any idea.

My search code is
searchquery is my search data

```
let regexexp = new RegExp(searchquery,'i');
s = {"name": regexexp};

function callback(totalcount){
     db.collection("customers").find(s).limit(16).toArray(function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        responsedata = { status: true,error : false,data : res };
        resolve(responsedata);
      });
  }
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: What if you ignore whitespaces altogether? `let regexexp = new RegExp(searchquery.split('').join('\\s*'),'i');`?

Comment: Thanks for your response it works but when i pass like this in URL and it converts it to ?s=fn03%20a then my search API is not working any idea like it is not hitting but it works in Postman .

Comment: No idea what you mean. Make sure the `searchquery` is a literal text, not encoded URI param, before using it in a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest making any whitespace in the input optional:

```
let regexexp = new RegExp(searchquery.split('').join('\\s*'),'i');
```

Here,

- `searchquery.split('')` - splits the `searchquery` into separate chars
- `.join('\\s*')` - joins the splits back with `\s*` in between each, so that if there is any whitespace between `searchquery` chars, they could be matched, too.